# Does Stateful=False in Keras means only last batch matters

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

According to Keras's source code, stateful means the "state" is assigned to the `initial_state` of next batch, otherwise `initial_state` would be reinitialized.

What does `initial_state` mean? After reading the source code, my guess is it would correspond to all U, V and W in the below image ([source](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/)), but I have nothing to back that up. [image: below image]

Moreover, if `stateful=False`, does that mean only last batch matters?

Thank you